# Unable to select an element in the table

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am testing out Selenium recently to see if it can recognize my web app better than QTP.  So far it seems doing quite well. I ran into a problem trying to find an element within the table element. Some how I was not able to find master table but not the rows within the table.

[This is how the table looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cet2E.png)

The code below works fine...

```
WebElement BaseTable = driver.findElement(By.id("table_simpleBrowser|type=TradingInstrumentReport|!browser"));
```

Where as the code below does not...

```
BaseTable = driver.findElement(By.id("table_simpleBrowser|type=TradingInstrumentReport|!browser_tr_1"));
```

or

```
BaseTable = driver.findElement(By.className("even status_DEFAULT"));
```

or

```
WebElement BaseTable = driver.findElement(By.id("table_simpleBrowser|type=TradingInstrumentReport|!browser"));
BaseTable = BaseTable.findElement(By.className("even status_DEFAULT"));
```

Can someone please help to show me how I can retrieve the a certain value in the table by finding the element in certain row/column in the table?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`even` and `status_DEFAULT` are actually two classes of this web element. `By.className()` receives only one class as parameter. It should be

```
findElement(By.className("even"));
// or
findElement(By.className("status_DEFAULT"));
```

To find element by the two classes use `By.cssSelector()`

```
findElement(By.cssSelector(".even.status_DEFAULT")); // note the dot before each class name
```

However it seems that its not unique enough. I recommend you search by id which contains `browser_tr_1`

```
findElement(By.cssSelector("[id*=`browser_tr_1`]"));
```

Comment: Thanks for the information.  I actually find out why I cannot find the element by ID finally.  It is sync issue.  The master table has already been created even the search table is not filled up yet.  I actually need to put in a WebDriverWait statement to make sure the first row exits before I start the data extraction codes and it works.